# NUXTJS: How do I update data() variable from client side javascript

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

```js
data() {
  const ports = [
    {
      subtitle: "PORT 1",
      title: "COM8",
    },
    {
      subtitle: "PORT 2",
      title: "COM11",
    },
  ];

  return {
    ports,
  };
},
```

I have a server side variable named **ports**. I want to update/add items to it and hope vue renderer updates it reactively.

will javascript below would work?

```html
<script>
  this.ports.push({ title: devicePort, subtitle: deviceName });
</script>
```

**EDIT1:** I'd like to make it clear that I am calling script block above from client side browser.

**EDIT2:** Followed kissu's answer, problem is I'm getting **"Uncaught Reference Error: addOne is undefined"** error from  browser client javascript

e.g.

What I did is just call addOne()  from browser client javascript

e.g.

```
setTimeout(function( {
  addOne(); //undefined
},100)
```

**EDIT3:** as per @kissu request

```js
//websocket running on browser

ws.on("message", function (msg) {
  addOne(); 
  // **"Uncaught Reference Error: addOne is undefined"**
}
```

Comment: Where is this code located? `ws.on("message", function (msg) {`

Comment: browser client side. user that is browsing the site.

Comment: This doesn't mean anything tbh. Nuxt (and Vue behind it) is a client side JS framework too.

Comment: if  browser client side will not work. I guess I need to create a new question on how to call vue methods via API rest call. something like vanilla fetch API would do?

Comment: I don't understand `if browser client side will not work`, how some client side code can not work? `vue methods via API rest call`, you don't call a client side Vue method via a call on some API call. What does it even mean? Those 2 things are totally unrelated. You can use the vanilla `fetch` method or some `axios` yes.

Comment: axios only works within the context of vue, if only I can wire vue methods that is callable within browser (vanilla) javascript then I'm done :D

Comment: Axios can work on client, on server and hence, in a Vue/Nuxt context.

Comment: one last thing lol. so the route would be fetch('http://localhost:port/page/addOne') ... ?

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about here but probably not, this is somehow the behavior of a router -> controller in a MVC backend code context. You don't do that kind of stuff on the frontend because there is no server listening for an HTTP call.

Comment: yeah I guess I'm stuck on backend thing (too much REST/API dependency) and can't absorb the nature of vue lifecycle.

Comment: I'm not sure of what is your background but yeah, backend and frontend are 2 totally different beasts. You can't do the same thing in both and a communication with the 2 is not trivial. But so far, what you're asking is not making any sense on a frontend unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it should be written in Vue2

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <pre>{{ array }}</pre>
    <button @click="addOne">Add one object to the array</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      array: [
        {
          subtitle: 'PORT 1',
          title: 'COM8',
        },
        {
          subtitle: 'PORT 2',
          title: 'COM11',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addOne() {
      this.array.push({ title: '3000', subtitle: 'Samsung' })

      // the one below is a bit more bulletproof, more info here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays
      // this.$set(this.array, this.array.length, { title: '3000', subtitle: 'Samsung' })
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: How do I call it via javascript? not from a button click but some form of an event like websocket?

Comment: @agentpx use a callback function on the websocket and call the method.

Comment: Yeah l have lots of methods like this but never came to my mind to call it instead of directly updating the variable. I will try this. I'm new to nuxtjs. Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting  Uncaught ReferenceError: addOne is not defined.

Comment: @agentpx please understand that I cannot help you with some code if I don't see the actual code.

Comment: @agentpx your edit is not giving any more info since it's a `setTimeout` with no real useful context. Btw, why do you need a `setTimeout` if you're working with websockets? Also, I'm not sure if you're reading the documentation for Vue2 (Nuxt supports only it as of today), but if it's the case, you should actually write  `addOne()` (because Vue2 is based on Options API).

Comment: what I mean in my edit is vanilla javascript not server side rendered. :D @kissu

Comment: @agentpx what do you mean by `vanilla javascript not server side rendered`? You're in a VueJS context here, you pretty much need to follow the conventions. And the JS logic used there is "vanilla JS".

Comment: see my EDIT3 on question. setTimeout is just a way to call addOne arbitrally to test if vanilla javascript call will succeed. Thanks.

Comment: yes because websocket is on client side, that's is why I need to update vue component that is on the server side. I'm trying to take advantage the Reactivity of component.

Comment: @agentpx there is no `server side component` as so to speak. To take advantage of the reactivity, use the websockets in a proper context via some lifecycle hooks and track it accordingly.